# split a list according to size of float entries

Tags: python

I have a list of floats where the size at each sequential index can vary.
i.e.

```
float_list = [167.233, 95.6242, 181.367, 20.6354, 147.505, 41.9396, 20.3126]
```

What I am trying to do is to split the list according to the size of the floats in the indices. In particular, if the float at one index is less than that at the index before, then group the indices together to return the total number of indices that are less than those before.

For example, if we start from the first index the value is 167.233. Because the value at the next index, 95.6242, is smaller than that of the one prior, I would like to group these two together to return their length i.e. 2.

The third index is larger than the second, so this becomes the new 'benchmark'. Since the following index is smaller than that at the third, this returns the length 2.
The fifth index is the next 'benchmark' and the floats at the remaining indices decrease, therefore returning the length of those indices 3.

The way in which I would like this returned, is a list of the length of those indices i.e [2,2,3]

Apologies in advance if this is confusing, it is difficult to explain in words.

Comment: ok so what have you attempted to do?

Comment: SO is not HW solution site :) ! Please post your tries and then people will help you @user3227150

Comment: This question is difficult to understand as written.  Your use of the work index and indices seems confused with the values in a list.  Could you at lease propose what your prefered output would be?

Comment: What would you expect `[167.233, 168.2, 181.367, 20.6354]` to return?

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.diff` and `numpy.where` in order to find the indices that the items are not ordered, then use `numpy.split()` to split the array in that indices, and finally use `map()` to find the length of splitted arrays:

```
In [19]: import numpy as np
In [20]: float_list = np.array([167.233, 95.6242, 181.367, 20.6354, 147.505, 41.9396, 20.3126])
# In [22]: np.split(float_list, np.where(np.diff(float_list) > 0)[0] + 1)
# Out[22]: 
# [array([ 167.233 ,   95.6242]),
#  array([ 181.367 ,   20.6354]),
#  array([ 147.505 ,   41.9396,   20.3126])]

In [23]: map(len, np.split(float_list, np.where(np.diff(float_list) > 0)[0] + 1))
Out[23]: [2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like following:

```
def group_list(l):
    if not l:
        return []

    result = [0]
    prev = l[0] + .1
    for el in l:
        if el < prev:
            result[-1] += 1
        else:
            result.append(1)
        prev = el

    return result

>>> group_list([167.233, 95.6242, 181.367, 20.6354, 147.505, 41.9396, 20.3126])
[2, 2, 3]
>>> group_list([167.233, 95.6242, 1.367, 20.6354, 147.505, 41.9396, 20.3126])
[3, 1, 3]
>>> group_list([167.233, 95.6242, 1.367, 20.6354, 147.505, 41.9396, 70.3126])
[3, 1, 2, 1]
>>> group_list([-167.233, 95.6242, 1.367, 20.6354, 147.505, 41.9396, 70.3126])
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sens to return [0] when the argument is an empty list.

Comment: Maybe not, OP can tune this function to his specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to obtain a list containing the sizes of decreasing/non-increasing ranges in the list of floats.

```
def size_of_decreasing_ranges(float_list):
    if len(float_list) == 0:
        return []
    result = []
    count = 1
    for index, ele in enumerate(float_list):
        if index > 0:
            if float_list[index] > float_list[index-1]:
                result.append(count)
                count = 1
            else:
                count += 1
    result.append(count)
    return result
```